# Switch between on/off values in an rhandsontable column

Tags: r, dropdown, rhandsontable

I would like to know if it is possible to switch between on/off values in an rhandsontable column. It could be probably done with a dropdown option with on/off levels.

```
DF = data.frame(Label = paste("Item",as.integer(1:50)),
                    Sel= factor(rep("On",50)),
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    rhandsontable(DF,width =350,height = 300)
  })
```

This is an example:
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by 'switching'?

Comment: I editted by adding a picture